# matplotlib/IPython Notebook creates empty PNG or PDF image

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

This code produces a boxplot using matplotlib. The plot is shown correctly in the IPython Notebook (see attached image). However, `savefig` creates an empty image. I tried the file endings `.png` and `.pdf`, but this happens with both. What is wrong with the code?

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()


GCEMA     = (0.26, 0.26, 0.30, 0.51, 0.55, 0.34)
CEM       = (0.26, 0.23, 0.30, 0.49, 0.35, 0.24)
selSCAN   = (0.19, 0.35, 0.28, 0.45, 0.41, 0.52)
selSCANAD = (0.26, 0.52, 0.37, 0.46, 0.46, 0.47)
N=6
pos = np.arange(N)
ax = plt.axes()

ax.bar(0.6*pos, GCEMA, width = 0.10, color='green', label='GCE-MA')
ax.bar(0.6*pos+0.1, CEM, 0.10, color='blue', label='CE-M')
ax.bar(0.6*pos+0.2, selSCAN, 0.10, color='red', label='selSCAN-ND')
ax.bar(0.6*pos+0.3, selSCANAD, 0.10, color='yellow', label='selSCAN-AD')
ylabel("quality [$\phi$]", fontsize=14)
fig.set_size_inches(5,4)
xticks(rotation=15)
xticks([0.2,0.8,1.4,2,2.6,3.2],['PGP','CAIDA','coPapersDBLP','soc-LiveJournal','uk-2002','eu-2005'])
legend(loc=4, fontsize=10)
show()
savefig("cond.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to use `savefig` before `show`.

Comment: thanks, simple solution; in python console having show before does not create a problem - in ipython it does

Comment: Nice! Incidentally, the problem also takes place if one cell ends with some plot, and a following cell does the ``savefig``. For the ``savefig`` to work, it should be performed in the same cell as the plot. This probably follows by an implicit ``show`` in one of IPython's _repr_* (``_repr_png``?), and so the answer above works as well.